# select SVG element's attribute "id" in React

Tags: reactjs, svg

How I can select the SVG element's "g" attribute "id" : as mentioned below "SvgElement" in react

like :

```
<svg id="L_1" data-name="L 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="720" viewBox="0 0 920 420">

    <rect id="Background" width="1920" height="720" fill="none"/>

    <g id="SvgElement">
        <circle cx="200" cy="100" r="50"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Have you tried to do that with a `ref`?
https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Why don't you render the SVG with React?

Comment: Are you trying to pass the SVG's g element's id to some client side script? You can use a ref function to get the containing element after they've been added to the DOM.